# How to generate map of routes from a list of routes classes

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to automate the routes assignment in my app, by creating a list of routes.
Then this list will be mapped.My aim is to improve my existing code.
I know this is confusing you can better understand it by the code given below:

```
MaterialApp(
        navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[observer],
        home: getWidgetByRouteName(hasRoute), //GameDetails(),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          SplashPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) => SplashPage(),
          Phone.routeName: (BuildContext context) => Phone(),
          OTP.routeName: (BuildContext context) => OTP(),
          Team.routeName: (BuildContext context) => Team(),

        },
      ),
```

I want to convert the above code into this type:

```
    List route = [SplashPage, Phone, OTP];

    Map<String, WidgetBuilder> namedRoutes = {};

    route.forEach((element) {
      namedRoutes[element.routeName] = (BuildContext context) => element();
    });



  MaterialApp(
        navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[observer],
        home: getWidgetByRouteName(hasRoute), //GameDetails(),
        routes: namedRoutes
      ),
```

and in case you are confused what is routeName :

```
class SplashPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/splash';
..
..
..
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MainApp(dirty):
Class '_Type' has no instance getter 'routeName'.
Receiver: SplashPage
Tried calling: routeName
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an instance of a class from a Type object representing the class, at least not without mirrors (and neither the Flutter nor the web platform supports mirrors).

Comment: is there anyway around possible ??

Comment: I really don't know the workaround. A lot of libraries do the stuff as your example(dictionary)